# Loader like on google+

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to create a loader(progress) view like on google+. Can you recommend an easy way to do it? Here is the screen:

[image: Loader of google+]

Comment: Take a look at http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

In your Entry-Activities `onCreate`:

1. Create and show a `ProgressDialog`
2. Create an `AsyncTask`
3. Put your loading code in the `doInBackground` Method of your task
4. Dismiss the `ProgressDialog` in `onPostExecute` of your task